# I want to update my text value when I check checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a form, it has a checkbox ,  value(how many item do you want) ,  item(ex: pen,eraser).
My value set 0,I hope when I checked, value will turn 0 -> 1
This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr><th>checkbox</th><th>value</th><th>item</th></tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
        <%     

          String sql = "select * from send"; 
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  
             ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); 
             pstmt.setQueryTimeout(60);
             while(rs.next()){ 
                         String name = rs.getString("name");  
     String c_id = rs.getString("c_id");
                    out.print("<tr><td>"+"<input type=checkbox name='a'id='a' value="+c_id+" onclick='testfun( this,"+c_id+")'>"+"</td>"
                + "<td><input type=text id='"+c_id+"' value=0 SIZE=5></td><td>"+name+"</td></tr> "); 
                   }
                    rs.close(); 
            %>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
unction testfun(element, c_id) {
var x = document.getElementById('c_id');
 //if check-box is checked
 if (element.checked) {

x.value ="1";

 } else {
x.value ="0";
 }
```

}

```
</script>
```

how can I do ?I dont know why I can not change value?
thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `c_id` to your input-box and pass same to your `function` i.e: `testfun()` with current checkbox clicked using `this` .Like below :

**Jsp code** :

```
out.print("<tr><td>"+"<input type='checkbox' name='a' value="+c_id+" onclick='testfun( this ,'"+c_id+"')'>"+"</td>" + "<td><input type='text' id='"+c_id+"' name='count' value=0 SIZE=5></td><td>"+name+"</td></tr> ");
```

**Js code** :

```
function testfun(element, cName) {
  var x = document.getElementById(cName);
  //if check-box is checked
  if (element.checked) {
    //assign required value
    x.value = 1;

  } else {
    x.value = 0;
  }
}
```

**Demo code** :

```js
function testfun(element, cName) {
  var x = document.getElementById(cName);
  //if check-box is checked
  if (element.checked) {
//assign required value
x.value = 1;

  } else {
x.value = 0;
  } }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="ddnd" onclick="testfun(this,'a')" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="ddnd" onclick="testfun(this,'b')" />2

<input type="text" id="a" />
<input type="text" id="b" />
```

Comment: hi,swati,  I have try your code, it still cant change value.I have test it,  I add window.alert('hello'); in if (element.checked) condition. it will show hello when I check,but value cant change.

Comment: Did you change your jsp code as above code or not? Also, check if value pass from function i.e `c_id` is assign to `id` of your input or not.Also,show your updated code as well it would be easy to identify error. Lastly , check if your browser console has any error or not .

Comment: My console show Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at testfun (index.jsp:82)

Comment: What does `cName` have in it ? Check and see onces, Also from where you are getting `c_id` value?

Comment: I lost to paste this line  String c_id = rs.getString("c_id");,and I have change cname to c_id , but still not work,sorry ,I am new

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210414/discussion-between-swati-and-samurai).

Comment: hello,I solve the problem ,thanks. I remove my outprint and slove it.I have paste my code in chat room.

Answer (score 0):

You have `getElementById` but are giving it the value from the element's "name" attribute. Add `id='a'` to your checkbox input and it should work.